# Find index of min and max element in vector of user defined struct

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
struct ColorSpacePoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}

std::vector<ColorSpacePoint> v{...}; // Initialized with data

auto minMaxY = std::minmax_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
    [](ColorSpacePoint const& lhs, ColorSpacePoint const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.Y < rhs.Y;
});

std::pair<ColorSpacePoint, ColorSpacePoint> result = 
    std::make_pair(ColorSpacePoint{minMaxY.first->X, minMaxY.first->Y}, 
                   ColorSpacePoint{minMaxY.second->X, minMaxY.second->Y});
```

Using this code, result contains the minimum and maximum element. How can I alter the code to also retrieve an std::pair of the indices:

```
std::pair<int, int> resultIndices = ... ;
```

Comment: Protip: If you use [`pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), instead of your own custom `pair`: `ColorSpacePoint`, it already has comparison operators defined so you can use [`minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax), alternatively define your comparison operators and use `minmax`.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the iterators, which is all you need:

```
const auto resultIndices = std::make_pair(
   std::distance(std::begin(v), minMaxY.first),
   std::distance(std::begin(v), minMaxY.second)
);
```

Since vector storage is contiguous, this is effectively just a pointer subtraction and thus blazingly fast.